# An expandable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a div where one of the children is visible and one is out of the div, I've been using overflow:hidden for this, however whatever i try i can't seem to get this to work, I've tried positioning one absolute and that works, but as soon as I extend the div to reveal the extention it will overlap it obviously. Any help would be great, here are some pictures of the main concept.

[Before Being Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa5hZ.jpg)

[After Being Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdMmS.jpg)

note: I am using react js to develop this, if you could make a codepen or something in vanilla javscript just as a concept of the main functionality and then I will convert it to react.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not make the button and the expandable div children of the same parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```css
.expandable {
  position: relative;
}

.expandable>div {
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.expandable>div>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
.expandable>input { display: none; }
.expandable>label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 210px;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-image: url('https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/arrow--v1.png');
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.expandable>input:checked+label {
  left: 410px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.expandable>input:checked~div {
  width: 400px;
}

.expandable>div>div {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="expandable">
  <input type=checkbox id='ex1'>
  <label for='ex1'></label>
  <div>
    <div>
      <!-- right side content -->
      <h1>Stuff here</h1>
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This uses the label as the button.  When clicked, it triggers the input to be checked/unchecked.  We then use the status of the checkbox to change our CSS, and we use transitions so that it is smooth, works across all modern browsers, and is very battery efficient for mobile devices.